# How to enforce one-to-one object reference when instantiating?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Say I have an object named apple

```
Apple apple = new Apple();
```

And I have a class named `AppleHolder` that looks like this:

```
class AppleHolder{
   private Apple apple;

   public AppleHolder(Apple apple){
      this.apple = apple;
   }
}
```

An `Apple` instance cannot have more than 1 `AppleHolder`. But, of course, when I do this:

```
AppleHolder appleHolder1 = new AppleHolder(apple);
AppleHolder appleHolder2 = new AppleHolder(apple);
```

This will make it seem as though `apple` has two holders when it can only have 1. Is there a design pattern to make the second instantiation above return `appleHolder1` instead?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know of such a pattern. You can have a back reference. If you try to change it and it's not `null`, throw an `IllegalStateException`

Comment: Maybe if you had a `setApple(Apple apple)` function instead of having to pass in an apple through the constructor of the AppleHolder. And an Apple could probably have a flag to tell if it's being held.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That was my initial idea. If I cannot find such pattern then I might take your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern, only limiting the relationship between objects rather than their instantiation.

Modified to your use-case (assuming a one-to-one relationship between `Apple` and `AppleHolder`), it would look something like:

```
class Apple {
    private AppleHolder appleHolder;

    public AppleHolder getAppleHolder() {
        return this.appleHolder;
    } 

    // Rest of class...
}

class AppleHolder {
    private Apple apple;

    private AppleHolder(Apple apple) {
        this.apple = apple;
    }

    public static AppleHolder getAppleHolder(Apple apple) {
        if(apple.getAppleHolder() != null) {
            return apple.getAppleHolder();
        } else {
            return new AppleHolder(apple);
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, an `Apple` can only have one `AppleHolder` and an `AppleHolder` can only have one `Apple`.

Rather than calling the constructor for `AppleHolder`, you call the static method: `AppleHolder.getAppleHolder(apple);`.

If an `AppleHolder` already exists for the `Apple` provided, then the the `AppleHolder` for that `Apple` is returned.

Else, a new `AppleHolder` is created and returned.

Answer (score 1):

Youare looking for something called a Singleton pattern.

Normally you would need a helper method to get the instance and not do it with a constructor.

For example:

```
class AppleHolder {
    static private AppleHolder apple = null;
    // prevent any object construction outside of this class
    private AppleHolder() {
    }
    public synchronized AppleHolder getInstance() {
        if (null == apple) {
            apple = new AppleHolder();
        }
        return apple;
    }
}
```

The synchronized keyword helps ensure that there won't be any concurrency issues
and your constructor can do whatever you want for the singleton instance.

There are other ways to handle this and Joshua Bloch's book *Effective Java* has some good discussion around it and you can do a web search on "Singleton Pattern" to find more.

Comment: Thanks but what if I have another Apple object, say `apple2`, and I want it to have its own AppleHolder too. The Singleton pattern might not be ideal for that case.